# Sample DateTime Format given Regex Pattern

Tags: regex, datetime

I've reviewed the Regex documentation online but can't seem to make much progress on this.
I'm trying to understand what the format of a DateTime is given a specific regex pattern.
So what would a sample DateTime string look like that followed this regex pattern:

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}\-.+T[^\.]+(Z|[\+\-].+)
```

Currently I'm passing in the following DateTime:

```
2016-03-10T23:34:32.1898018Z
```

to a web service that validates the contents based on the regex described above (which is failing).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if you remove your milliseconds from your test input, it would match. Therefore, if you want that format to match, you could change the regex to read

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}\-[0-1]?[1-9]\-[0-3]?[0-9]+T.+[\.][0-9]+(Z|[\+\-].+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the diagram, it's very helpful!
I will remove the milliseconds and see if it works...

Comment: No problem. By the way, the extra part of the regex at the beginning (`\-[0-1]?[1-9]\-[0-3]?[0-9]+`) makes sure that the date portion is entered a certain way. In your expression, this would match: 2016-03T23:34:32Z

Answer (score 1):

The regex you mention can parse those kinds of dates :

- 2009-06-15T13:45:30-07:00 (UTC-7 timezone)
- 2009-06-15T13:45:30+07:00 (UTC+7 timezone)
- 2009-06-15T13:45:30Z ("Z" for UTC timezone)

if you want to parse this date 2016-03-10T23:34:32.1898018Z (with milliseconds), change the regexp to :

```
[1-9][0-9]{3}\-.+T[^\.]+\.[0-9]+(Z|[\+\-].+)
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, it really helped understanding this problem.